# how to select one tuple in rows based on variable field value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm quite new into SQL and I'd like to make a `SELECT` statement to retrieve only the first row of a set base on a column value. I'll try to make it clearer with a table example.
Here is my table data :

```
chip_id | sample_id
-------------------
1       | 45
1       | 55
1       | 5986
2       | 453
2       | 12
3       | 4567
3       | 9
```

I'd like to have a `SELECT` statement that fetch the first line with `chip_id=1,2,3`
Like this :

```
chip_id | sample_id
-------------------
1       | 45 or 55 or whatever
2       | 12 or 453 ...
3       | 9 or ...
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `45 or 55 or whatever` ?

Comment: If you are not bothered about sample_id, then can't you simple get DISTINCT of chip_id?

Comment: @Andomar : 45 or 55 or whatever, mean any value of sample_id for which chip_id=1

Answer (score 1):

i'd probably:

```
set a variable =0
order your table by chip_id
read the table in row by row
if table[row]>variable, store the table[row] in a result array,increment variable
loop till done
return your result array
```

though depending on your DB,query and versions you'll probably get unpredictable/unreliable returns.

Comment: @All : Found it, quite easy actually :

Answer (score 0):

You can get one value using `row_number()`:

```
select chip_id, sample_id
from (select chip_id, sample_id,
             row_number() over (partition by chip_id order by rand()) as seqnum
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

This returns a *random* value.  In SQL, tables are inherently unordered, so there is no concept of "first".  You need an auto incrementing id or creation date or some way of defining "first" to get the "first".

If you have such a column, then replace `rand()` with the column.

Comment: Since `rand()` is evaluated once per query (like `getdate()`) this would not actually return random rows.  Try `order by newid()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Provided I understood your output, if you are using PostGreSQL 9, you can use this:

```
SELECT chip_id , 
       string_agg(sample_id, ' or ')
FROM your_table
GROUP BY chip_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your data with a [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) query.
When you group, generally you want the max, the min, or some other values to represent your group. You can do sums, count, all kind of group operations.

For your example, you don't seem to want a specific group operation, so the query could be as simple as this one :

```
SELECT chip_id, MAX(sample_id)
FROM table
GROUP BY chip_id
```

This way you are retrieving the maximum `sample_id` for each of the `chip_id`.

Comment: Thanks Scori0, it does exactly what I want :)